# Inner Join in LINQ not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, linq

I have the following tables in this SQL database (some fields are irrelevant to this question):

[image: Diagram]

I have the following LINQ query:

```
Dim trips = From tr In db.tbl_Trips _
                    Join ds In db.tbl_tripDeptStations On tr.trip_ID Equals ds.tds_ID _
                    Where ds.tbl_Station.stn_County = county _
                    And tr.trip_StartDate >= startDate _
                    And tr.trip_EndDate <= endDate _
                    Select tr.trip_Name, tr.trip_StartDate, tr.trip_EndDate, tr.trip_SmallImage, tr.tbl_TourOperator.tourOp_Name
```

`startDate`, `endDate` and `county` are variables which I have declared in code above (not shown).

I am trying to show trips which have certain departure stations associated, based upon the county which can be found in the station table.

However, when I run the query, I get no results, and no error messages.

I also have this SQL query which works correctly:

```
SELECT distinct t.trip_ID, t.trip_Name, t.trip_StartDate, toop.tourOp_Name
FROM tbl_Trip AS t
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT tds.tds_trip
    FROM tbl_tripDeptStation AS tds
    INNER JOIN tbl_station AS s
    ON tds.tds_Stn = s.stn_ID
    WHERE s.stn_county = 'Greater London'
    ) AS ds
ON t.trip_ID = ds.tds_trip
INNER JOIN tbl_TourOperator AS toop ON t.tourOp_ID = toop.tourop_id
WHERE t.trip_StartDate >= @StartDate AND t.trip_EndDate <= @EndDate
ORDER BY t.trip_
```

Can anyone shed some light as to where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Are you using entity framework?

Comment: I'm using a DBML file so I guess so? Might be slightly outdated.

Comment: Where is the JOIN to tbl_station in your first LINQ query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're using entity framework,

```
var ds = from tds in tbl_tripdeptstation
join s in tbl_station on tds.tds_stn equals s.stn_id
where s.stn_country.equals("somecountry")
select new {tds.trip};

var result = (from t in tbl_trip
join ds2 in ds on t.trip_id equals ds2.trip
join toop in tbl_touroperator on t.tourop_id equals toop.tourop_id
where t.trip_start >= SomeDate AND t.trip_enddate <= EndDate
select new { t.trip_ID, t.trip_Name, t.trip_StartDate, toop.tourOp_Name}).Distinct().OrderBy(r => r.trip_);
```

Comment: I started programming in vb, but i got into a c# project like 3 months ago...I don't think i'll ever go back :P

Comment: Thanks for this - it works brilliantly, with the exception of the OrderBy part at the end of the query, there seems to be an unknown variable 'r', which isn't recognised. I need to order it by trip_startdate. I have tried adding an 'Order By' part after the 'where' part, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. Cheers for your help - much appreciated!