# Order by not working in LINQ query

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I'm using the following query using the Linq to SQL framework (DBML files). This was from a previous question - [Inner Join in LINQ not working correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259651/inner-join-in-linq-not-working-correctly/19263884).

The `Order By` part does not appear  to work. It simply orders by title, then by startdate. How can I get the query to order by just the startdate?

```
Dim ds = From tds In db.tbl_tripDeptStations _
                Join s In db.tbl_Stations On tds.tds_Stn Equals s.stn_ID _
                Where s.stn_County.Equals(county) _
                Select New With {tds.tds_Trip}

        Dim result = (From t In db.tbl_Trips _
                      Join ds2 In ds On t.trip_ID Equals ds2.tds_Trip _
                      Join toop In db.tbl_TourOperators On t.tourOp_ID Equals toop.tourOp_ID _
                      Where t.trip_StartDate >= startDate And t.trip_EndDate <= endDate And t.trip_StartDate >= Date.Today() _
                      Order By t.trip_StartDate _
                      Select New With {t.trip_ID, t.trip_Name, t.trip_StartDate, toop.tourOp_Name}).Distinct()
```

Comment: Does the ORDER BY work if you remove the `.Distinct()` ?

Comment: Ah yes, thanks - that's fixed it. Do I need the distinct in there? There seem to be the same number of results returned without it. How does distinct in this particular situation work? Thanks again.

Comment: I think it depends on whether the `ds` subquery can return duplicate `trip_ID` or not. If it can return duplicates, you could rewrite the `Join ds2 In ds ...` to the equivalent of `EXISTS` in Linq.

Comment: you could also do the `.Distinct()` part of the query, then do your `.OrderBy()` after.

Answer (score 0):

Except for the `ThenBy` type of operators operators aren't guaranteed to keep the order (and a lot of them actually don't due to implementation being complex / slow if they did).

If you want your query to represent an Ordered collection, you should call `OrderBy` type of operators last in a query, in your case you are using Distinct at the end which breaks the order guarantee, it's not specific to distinct at all and could have happened with many other operators

In the case of your sample, remove the order by where you've put it and after distinct add this:

```
.OrderBy(item=>item.trip_StartDate);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately the 'item' part isn't recognized. It just underlines in red in Visual Studio. What do I need to change this to?

Comment: you don't need to change it, item is both defined and used in the same place, you'll need to show me what you typed for me to tell you what to change so please update your question with your now non working code.